# Export pyvis graph as vector or .png image. Is there a way?

Tags: python, graph, pyvis

I'm looking for a way to export a huge Graph generated with pyvis in to a vector graphic .svg or at least .png format. Is there a way to do it? So far I've only found the option to save / export as .html file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this worked:

- save the graph to HTML file
- open the HTML in a new tab
- right-click -> save image as ...

Answer (score 0):

def generate_png(url_file, name):
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        file = open(url_file, "r").read()
        page.set_content(file, wait_until="load")
        page.wait_for_timeout(30000)
        page.screenshot(path=f'{name}.png', full_page=True)
        file.close()
        browser.close()
```