# Save network image from Pyvis python

Tags: python, graph, pyvis

I have a network created through Pyvis library:

```
nt = Network('900px', '900px')
nt.from_nx(N)
nt.show('plot.html')
```

Where N is a network from Networkx library.
In the last line I create an html file with the plot of the network but when I open it I can't take a screenshot of the entire graph because it is too big and if I try to zoom out, the names of the nodes disappear. Is there a correct way to save the image in Pyxis library?

Comment: Found this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629495/export-pyvis-graph-as-vector-or-png-image-is-there-a-way** response useful

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution for a long time. Without the use of chromium, it turned out to be impossible to do this. First, you need to install dependencies.

*# pip install pytest-playwright*
*# playwright install*

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

nt = Network('900px', '900px')
nt.from_nx(N)
nt.write_html(<name>.html)

def generate_png(url_file, name):
    
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        for browser_type in [p.chromium]:
            browser = browser_type.launch()
            page = browser.new_page()
            file = open(url_file, "r").read()
            page.set_content(file, wait_until="load")
            page.wait_for_timeout(30000) # this timeout for correctly render big data page
            page.screenshot(path=f'{name}.png', full_page=True)
            browser.close()
            #file.close()
generate_png(<name>.html, graph)
```

Next, we just save the html and open it via chromium to save the image.
It is enough to pass the correct html file paths and the name of the desired png file.

Comment: Hi Andrey Stepankin, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks

Comment: Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.